# Runtime Error 9 - Subscript out of range in Print Program on Page Breaks

Tags: excel, vba, page-break

I have created a multi-sheet financial file containing 1 sheet for each month. The data on each sheet is exactly the same size and shape (A1 to V186). Each sheet contains 2 print program buttons; one to print a detail report, and the other to print a summary report. The same 2 buttons are on each sheet running the same 2 programs and use variables to get the code name and index number of the active sheet. The summary print uses A4 Portrait, no page breaks and works fine; but the A3 Landscape 2 page breaks in the detail report are a real problem for me to solve. I have spent 2 full days researching and trying all different suggested solutions to get the page breaks to work,(Location, Before, etc etc) and I just can't work it out. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Print_Month_Detail()
'
' Print_Month_Detail Macro
'

 Dim CShtIdx As Integer
 Dim SheetName As String

 CShtIdx = ActiveSheet.Index
 SheetName = ActiveSheet.CodeName

 Worksheets(CShtIdx).Activate

 ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
 Worksheets(CShtIdx).ResetAllPageBreaks
 Set Worksheets(CShtIdx).HPageBreaks(1).Location = Worksheets(CShtIdx).Range("A70")
 Set Worksheets(CShtIdx).HPageBreaks(2).Location = Worksheets(CShtIdx).Range("A138")
'
 Application.PrintCommunication = False
 ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$V$186"
 With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
     .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$2"
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""

'   ...... more print settings.......


    End With
'
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Preview:=True, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: My guess would be that `ResetAllPageBreaks` deletes them, and therefore there is no `HPageBreaks(1)` or `HPageBreaks(2)`. I'd think the solution would be to add them, and then set the `Location`. I don't have Excel handy on this tablet to test that, though.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion braX. I removed the ResetAllPageBreaks; set the page breaks manually, then ran the program. It ran without a hitch. But after I ran the Summary report and re-ran the Detail report, I got the same error; but after running it for a second time, it was fine. I wondered why it was OK on the second run, so removed the Application.PrintCommunication = False to see what was going on. I ran both reports again. Everything is fine. Go figure! I don't know why removing the line 'Application.PrintCommunication = False' fixed the error; but so glad it all works now.